# Prove the boundary of a generalized rectangle has Jordan content $0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> A bounded subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is said to have *Jordan content*
>   $0$ provided for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a finite collection
>   $\mathcal{F}$ of generalized rectangles of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that cover
>   $S$, the sum of whose volume is less than $\epsilon$. That is, if
>   $\mathcal{F} = \{\mathbf{I}_{1}, \ldots, \mathbf{I}_{m}\}$, then
>
> $$S \subseteq \bigcup_{i\leq j  \leq m} \mathbf{I}_{j} \hspace{1em}
> > \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^{m} \text{vol}(\mathbf{I}_{i}) < \epsilon. $$

Prove that the boundary of a generalized rectangle has Jordan content $0$

---

I tried this as follows:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and let the generalized rectangle be $\mathbf{I} = [a_1, b_1] \times \cdots \times [a_n, b_n]$. Consider any boundary side of the generalized rectangle. Then

$$\mathbf{J} = [a_1, b_1] \times \cdots \times [a_{n - 1}, b_{n - 1}] \times \left[-\frac{\epsilon}{3(b_1 - a_1)\cdots (b_n - a_n)}, \frac{\epsilon}{3(b_1 - a_1) \cdots (b_{n - 1} - a_{n - 1})} \right] $$

has volume $2\epsilon/3 < \epsilon$ and it contains the boundary we're considering.  Hence, the boundary has Jordan content $0$.

But this doesn't prove it for the entire generalized rectangle. Can someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: The last coordinate of $J$ is close to zero. If $0\notin[a_n,b_n]$ then $J$ might be disjoint with $I$. Once you write a proper $J$ that does the job, count how many sides of $I$ you would need to cover (which only depends on $n$) and multiply that number by the volume of $J$.

Comment: It should be $2n$. Each coordinate you have $2$ faces by making that coordinate either $a_i$ or $b_i$. Regardless, that number is a constant. If the volume of $J$ goes to zero, it still goes to zero after being multiplied by that constant.

Comment: Okay yes $2n$ makes more sense. How can I come up with a proper $J$? Sorry my English is not so great so maybe I am misunderstanding your suggestion.

Comment: If the face is the one making the $i$-th coordinate $a_i$ then take $J$ to have $[a_i-\epsilon,a_i+\epsilon]$ in the corresponding factor. If it is the opposite face, i.e. the $i$-th coordinate is $b_i$, then take the factor to be $[b_i-\epsilon,b_i+\epsilon]$. You can divide the $\epsilon$ by the volume of the face, like you did above, but it doesn't matter at the end.

Comment: Can I take $J = [a_1, b_1, \times \cdots \times [a_{n - 1}, b_{n- 1}] \times [a_{n} -\frac{\epsilon}{4(b_1 - a_1) \cdots (b_{n - 1}-a_{n - 1})}, a_{n} + \frac{\epsilon}{4(b_1 - a_1) \cdots (b_{n - 1}-a_{n - 1})}]?$ Would this work? Then the volume is $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Comment: The last factor should include either $a_n$ or $b_n$. Just add $a_n$ or $b_n$ to both end-points. Like $[a_n-\frac{\epsilon}{...}, a_n+\frac{\epsilon}{...}]$ or $[b_n-\frac{\epsilon}{...}, b_n+\frac{\epsilon}{...}]$.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the original comment. Does that work now ? The volume becomes $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ still, I believe.